# vlc4j fails to load libvlc.so

Tags: java, jna, unsatisfiedlinkerror, vlcj

I am currently trying to programm a little webradio in Java on my raspberry pi (OS is raspibian). I wanted to use the VLC library, as it is capable of decoding nearly every stream automatically.
But I'm not even able to load the library on my Raspberry (no problems with Win 7). I am currently using vlc 2.1.3 (compiled it myself), therefor i use Lib4j 3.0.0 with JNA 4.0.0 and added the path of the library to the searchppath via

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "/home/pi/vlc-2.1.3/lib/.libs/");
```

I also tried

```
System.setProperty("jna.library.path","/home/pi/vlc-2.1.3/lib/.libs/");
```

and adding it via

```
-Djna.library.path=/home/pi/vlc-2.1.3/lib/.libs/
```

when executing the jar, but i always get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'vlc': Native library (linux-arm/libvlc.so) not found in resource path ([file:/home/pi/JavaProjects/Radio/Radio-release.jar])
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:271)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
    at main.Radio.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at main.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

I tried everything I found on the net about this and asked this question a few times before elsewhere but noone seems to know anything about it.

Has anyone encountered similar problems or does know the answer? (perhaps it is pretty simple, i hope so at least).

Thanks in advance for your help,

TheElk

--
Sorry for my probably bad english, I'm no native speaker :/

Comment: You mean like : System.setProperty("java.library.path","/home/pi/vlc-2.1.3/lib/.libs/"); ? This doesnt work, still the same error.

Comment: Is JNA actually supported on RPI? It would also be useful to know if the native library can be loaded via System.loadLibrary().

Comment: I added the path "/home/pi/vlc-2.1.3/lib/.libs/" to the java.library.path and tried System.load("libvlc.so") but i get another UnsatisfiedLinkError. (i checked first via java -XshowSettings:properties whether the path is correctly set). Is this what you wanted to know?
I am sure that it works somehow because i found another project where he used the vlc-lib on a raspy but the page has been removed :/

Comment: I think you need to pass -Djava.library.path=[whatever] when you start the JVM rather than using System.setProperty(...). After that, you tried exactly this: System.loadLibrary("vlc") ?

Comment: I tried it with System.setProperty(...) and -Djava.library.path= but it makes no difference. I also tried System.loadLibrary("vlc") and, with the full name, System.loadLibrary("libvlc.so") but i always get the Error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libvlc.so in java.library.path"
The java.library.path variable is set corectly:  java.library.path = /home/pi/vlc-2.1.3/lib/.libs/ (my installation folder of VLC)

Comment: So now it works. I don't know why, but it does. I simply installed vlc the "normal" way via "sudo apt-get install vlc" and now i have version 2.1.3. (I'm 100% sure this didnt work when i tried it a vew weeks ago) Now I just need to load the Library via: Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),LibVlc.class);
I will try to find out why it didnt work at first.
But nervertheless thanks for your help!

Comment: If that's the case, the libvlc.so you built yourself must either be corrupt in some way, or built for the wrong CPU architecture. Loading via Native.loadLibrary for JNA hould work now.

Comment: OK, i will try to recompile it then later. But how can it be wrong if i compiled it on pmy PI? Then it has to be corrupt? is There any way i can check its status?

Comment: No idea, but what else could it be if the official packaged vlc works. Maybe you could compare the directory structure and contents of the official build vs your own.

Comment: You can use `-Djna.debug_load=true` to see where JNA is looking for your library and any intermediate failures it encounters.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because vlcj doesn't support ARM yet.

You are getting that error because you are trying to load a native library (x86, x64) in an ARM processor.

I had a similar problem (trying to load vlcj in a raspberry pi), from my search, you should wait for the vlc team to support ARM or find another alternative.